# Python script gets stuck on dill.dump()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pickle, dill

I am writing a discord bot using a Python 3 and the Discord.py API wrapper (using asyncio). I am running a webserver to handle Atom Feed Notifications in the main thread and the discord client in a second thread.

I am using dill to save a dictionary of a custom class. The function gets run by the discord client (Thread 2) when the bot receives a chat message containing a valid command (Something changes in the dictionary.)

The script seems to get stuck on `dill.dump()`:

#### Functions

```
def save_object(obj, filename):
    f = open(filename, "wb")
    print("Opened file.")
    dill.dump(obj, f)
    print("Dumped to file.")
    f.close()
    print("Closed file.")
    return
def load_object(filename):
    f = open(filename, "rb")
    obj = dill.load(f)
    f.close()
    return obj
```

#### Calling Function

```
...
print('Saving Streamers')
save_object(Streamers, "streamers.dat")
print('Saving Youtubers')
save_object(Youtubers, "youtubers.dat")
```

I realize I could make the code look much better (and probably work more efficient) by working with a `with` block, this is merely a testing build (hence also the load of print statements). The output I received when I ran this was:

```
Saving Streamers
Opened file.
***NOTHING ON THIS LINE***
```

I do not get any sort of error message, the script simply stops outputting on that line and sort of freezes.

The file is visible in the file explorer, but contains 0 bytes.

When I force-quit the script with `CTRL+C`, the file ends up saving.

When I run the this code fragment manually in a python3 interpreter, it works fine (from the same working directory, read and write permissions are there since the script is run by root).

Comment: Hi! can you provide full code setup? you can try to wrap your `dill.dump` into  `try/except` to catch error

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was Global Interpreter Lock. The solution - for me - was to switch to multiprocessing instead of threading.